# Let $X$ be the union of open disk in $\Bbb R^2$ along with the tangent line $x =1$ then X is connected.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $X$ be the union of open disk in $\Bbb R^2$ along with the tangent line $x =1$ then X is connected.

Here I use the following *criterion* for $X$ to be connected:

A metric space $(X,d)$ is connected iff $A$ being a proper subset of $X$ implies $\delta A \neq \phi$.

Then in the above problem the tangent line $x =1$ is a proper subset and it has non-empty boundary. Can we conclude from here that the union of open disk in $\Bbb R^2$ along with the tangent line $x =1$ is connected?

Comment: No -- your criterion speaks (or ought to speak) about _all_ subsets if $X$, and you cannot show that it holds just by showing a single $A$ that happens to satisfy the property.

Comment: A better way of proceeding would be to prove that $X$ is _path connected_, if you know that "path connected" implies "connected".

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way here is to use the fact that path-connectedness implies connectedness. You will probably find the definition of path connectedness, and the proof of above implication, in the same book where you read the definition of connectedness.

This space is path-connected. Any point inside the open disk can be path-connected to the origin. Any point in the tangent line can be path connected to the point $(1,0)$. The origin and this point are connected by a path. Therefore the whole space is path-connected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach.

First, the open disc in $X$ is connected.

Next, the closure of any connected subset of a topological space is connected, so the closure of the open disc, a set I'll call $A$ which is the union of the open disc and the point $(x,y)=(1,0)$, is also connected. Also, the line $x=1$ is connected; call that set $B$.

Finally, any union of connected sets having nonempty intersection is connected, so $X=A \cup B$ is connected.